# Word describing people who need to establish trust, But aren't friends

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that would describe two people that need to establish trust between them but aren't friends. An example might be buyer and seller, if person A buys a car from person B. Both of them need to have some trust however they won't meet each other ever again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Counterparties" is the word that is used in the financial industry for parties at either end of a transaction. It's most frequently seen as part of the phrase "counterparty risk", which is the risk that a counterparty won't be able to hold up its end of the bargain.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved with a definition,and example usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider ***interdependent***.

> relating to two or more people or things dependent on each other
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interdependent</sup>

There is also a concept called ***buyer-seller interdependence*** in business markets.

> the close relationship between buyers and sellers, especially in organisational markets, where buyers become highly dependent on sellers for assured supply and delivery.
>
> [Monash Marketing Dictionary](http://www.buseco.monash.edu.au/mkt/dictionary/result.php?term=Buyer-Seller+Interdependence&submit=Go)

Furthermore, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interdependence) lists types of dependencies and explains the uncertainty and level of trust in social network interdependencies as below:

> Uncertainty: increases when perceived dependability and reliability of informal ties are lower. This is related to the level of trust that exists between the parties. Other authors like Sheppard and Sherman<sup>[26]</sup> believe uncertainty also differs depending on the form and depth of the relationship. Consequently, they proposed four levels ranging from ‘shallow interdependency’ to ‘deep interdependency’<sup>[26]</sup>
>
> <sup><sub>26. Sheppard, B. H.; Sherman, D. M. (1 July 1998). "THE GRAMMARS OF TRUST: A MODEL AND GENERAL IMPLICATIONS."</sub></sup>

Comment: Hmm it is interesting that someone downvotes this answer. I explained in detail why it is an interdependence and that there is a level of trust between parties.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the narrow case of a business relationship that consists of just one transaction, I don't think there is a single word answer. In the single transaction, buyer and seller would rely on *verification*, not trust. In other words, the buyer would inspect the product carefully (or have a trusted independent inspector evaluate it), and the seller would either demand cash or have a trusted independent authority (bank, etc.) verify that the buyer's means of payment (credit card, check, etc.) was legitimate.

However, in the case of a *recurring* business relationship, verifying every transaction might be inconvenient. For example, if I sell you a truck load of apples every week, it costs a lot of time for you to inspect each apple, and costs me time to make sure your check is good. In this case of recurring business, @ermanen is correct: "*interdependent*" is the right word.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks for the back-up also. Though, we can use "interdependent" in other contexts too and there are different levels of interdependency as well.

Comment: @ermanen : I would have made this a comment on yours (and given an up-vote), but as someone new to *English*.stackexchange.com, I can't do comments or up-votes yet.

Answer (score -2):

I think that [*acquainted*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acquainted) will go.

> acquainted - **adjective**, means *brought into social contact; made familiar*.

Comment: This seems to have no connection with the "trust" that the OP mentions.

Answer (score -2):

[Assurance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assurance) is defined by The Free Dictionary as

> A positive declaration intended to give confidence.